# Agregar líneas a lista python

Tags: python, tkinter

Alguien que me pudiera colaborar,
Python con tkinter
Tengo estas líneas de código formulario para agregar un abonado (código,nombre) en la lista abonados del archivo bdatos.py, pero no sé cómo agregarlo dentro de los [ ] de abonados[image]. Agradezco la ayuda.

a continuacion el codigo del archivo con el formulario

````
```
 python
import tkinter as tk
from bdatos import *

def add_abonado():
    codigo = codigo_entry.get()
    nombre = nombre_entry.get()
    abonado = f"['codigo':{codigo},'nombre':{nombre}]\n"
    
    with open("bdatos.py", "a") as f:
        f.write(abonado)
    codigo_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    nombre_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    

def open_add_abonado_window():
    global codigo_entry
    global nombre_entry
    
    add_abonado_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    add_abonado_window.title("Agregar abonado")
    
    codigo_label = tk.Label(add_abonado_window, text="Código:")
    codigo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    
    codigo_entry = tk.Entry(add_abonado_window)
    codigo_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    
    nombre_label = tk.Label(add_abonado_window, text="Nombre:")
    nombre_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    
    nombre_entry = tk.Entry(add_abonado_window)
    nombre_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    
    agregar_button = tk.Button(add_abonado_window, text="Agregar abonado", command=add_abonado)
    agregar_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)


# Crear ventana de Tkinter
root = tk.Tk()


# agregar botón para abrir formulario
add_abonado_button = tk.Button(root, text="Agregar abonado", command=open_add_abonado_window)
add_abonado_button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, padx=5, pady=5)
# Redimensionar ventana
root.geometry("1000x400+0+0")

root.mainloop()
```
````

sigue el codigo o listas en el archivo bdatos.py

```
abonados = []
   
   
   zonas = [
       {'codigo': '0001', 'nombre': 'Panel Demo' },
       {'codigo': '0456', 'nombre': 'Maria Garcia' },
       {'codigo': '0789', 'nombre': 'Pedro Martinez' },
       {'codigo': '7878', 'nombre': 'kkkkk' },
   ]
```

la idea es que con el formulario pueda agregar datos a la seccion o lista abonados misma estructura que zonas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Jhon. Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta pegando el código en la misma y no capturas de pantalla, así podemos ayudarte mucho mejor.

Comment: gracias @Seb0927 ya agregue el codigo, aclaro que este es algo simple para aprender. la idea es poder crear los formularios para agregar zonas tambien.